# GCJ Creates duplicate dummy symbol

Tags: java, gcc

I'm trying to build a java application with gcj but getting the error below.  It's been a while since I've used gcj (a year or so), so I may have forgot something non obvious but I'm pretty sure this is how I've always done it.

```
 multiple definition of `java resource .dummy'
```

gcj versions are 4.4.1 on Ubuntu and 4.3.4 on cygwin/windows XP and I'm building it with

```
  gcj --main=my.MainClass --classpath=my my/*java
```

Anyone seen this or know a workaround without installing an earlier version of gcj.  If that is the way to do it does anyone know how to do that on cygwin or will I have to build it?

Here is a minimal test case that gives this error

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new B());
    }
}

public class B {
    public String toString() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}

gcj --main=A src/A.java src/B.java
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 bugs filed against this [42143](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42143) and [43302](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43302)

The only reported solution is to compile to class files, then link the class files.

The following produces no errors:

```
gcj -I src -C src/A.java src/B.java
gcj -I src --main=A src/A.class src/B/class
```

Comment: Excellent, worked perfectly on both cygwin and ubuntu, thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you're building by compiling the *.java* files to *.o* files with `gcj -c`, you can also fix the problem by making the dummy symbols local with objcopy:

```
objcopy -L '_ZGr8_$_dummy' A.o
```

This works well with a Makefile -- just add to the `%.o: %.java` rule:

```
objcopy -L '_ZGr8_$$_dummy' $@
```

Answer (score 2):

At least with some version of gcj, explicitly specifying the output executable using -o will make it work:

> gcj --main=my.MainClass -o myexe --classpath=my my/*java

I have no explanation for this behaviour though.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution to the problem mentioned, but a way to compile to native code:
1. compile a jar archive using sun/openjdk
2. convert jar to executable using

```
gcj project.jar --main=package.name.ClassWithMainMethod
```